# Fit a textbox and a button inside a div

Tags: css, html

How can I put `<input type="text"/>` and `<input type="button"/>` in one line, like this...
[image: Example]
...so that they fit inside their parent (`<div>` for example), with textbox taking maximal possible width?

Of course, additional `div`s can be used. `table`s are allowed but discouraged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a table-based approach, you could:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" style="width:100%"/></td>
        <td style="width:60px"><input type="button" style="width:100%"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The effect is a table that fills its parent width containing a fixed-width button adjacent to a textbox that fills the remaining width.

Of course, out of habit, I would refactor the CSS into an external file.

Edit:

Here's a div-based approach:

*It happened to be the case that these div-based approaches worked well enough in IE 7 and IE8, but not Firefox*

```
<div>
    <div style="float:right; width:60px">
        <input type="button" style="width:100%"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" style="width:100%"/>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

And, perhaps, a lighter div-based approach:

```
<div>
    <input type="button" style="float:right; width:60px"/>
    <input type="text" style="width:100%"/>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

I recommend browser-testing div-based approaches.

Comment: Accepted and upvoted. Please remove <div> solutions because they don't work.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: Thanks for the feedback. We run IE at work, where it worked fine. Checked it against Firefox when I got home, and see that you are correct.